# show 1 post wordpress theme

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, content-management-system

[link](http://pastebin.com/EmjFuZ5y) this is my index.php of the theme
I try to modifiy the query_post but doesn't work
How can show only 1 post ??

Very thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find this line:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Then replace that line with this code:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

You can change the number 1, to whatever number you want if for example you need 3 posts.
Hope this help.

Comment: I have this code <?php query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$theme_home_cats); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Simply change:

```
query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$theme_home_cats);
```

To:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$theme_home_cats);
```